# Drawing straws using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, post, random

**CONTEXT**

Lately, I've been trying to make php draw straws. If you don't know what drawing straws is, it's basically someone getting someone else's name and that someone else gets another someone else's name etc. 
To make it more clear, the randomly generated output of the code should look like this:

(example with 4 people)

```
Person A drew person B
Person B drew person D
Person C drew person A
Person D drew Person B
```

**ATTEMPT 1**

To achieve this, I've tried using the following code:

```
$name = $_POST["names"]; // <-- name-array
$participants = $_POST["participants"]; // <-- stores the amount of participants
$arrX = $name;

for($i = 1; $i <= $participants[0]; $i++) {
    echo $name[$i-1];
     echo " drew ";
     ${"randIndex$i"} = array_rand($arrX, 1);
     echo $arrX[${"randIndex$i"}];
     echo "<br><br>";
}
```

**PROBLEM 1**

While this does deliver an output, it is not satisfactory.
A person can draw him/herself, which isn't allowed. I want the participants to draw a person other than themselves.

My best guess is that in order to fix this, I'd have to work with if-statements.
I just don't know how I would do that the most fitting way.

**edit: PROBLEM 2**

The same output also allows for two people to draw the same person.
I.e person A and B (and possibly more) draw person C. I want it so that everyone gets to draw a person which hasn't been drawn yet.

Comment: [`array_unique()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) could be of help.

Comment: How so? I think it would cause everyone to have the same person drawn..

Comment: Just FYI, what you explain as “drawing straws” here, isn’t actually what is generally referred to by that term to begin with. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawing_straws Just sayin’.

Comment: Wait, it isn't? But then again, this game is called ''lootjes trekken'' in my native language. I just google translated it into English and thought it was the exact same thing, oops..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution based on permutations.

```
$name = $_POST["names"]; // <-- name-array
$participants = $_POST["participants"]; // <-- stores the amount of participants

$last = $participants[0] - 1;
$map = range(0, $last);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $last; ++$i)
{
    if ($i != $last)
    {
        // randomly draw a person to the right
        $j = rand($i + 1, $last);

        // swap with the drawn person becoming no longer available for others since on their left
        $aux = $map[$i];
        $map[$i] = $map[$j];
        $map[$j] = $aux;
    }

    echo $name[$i], ' drew ', $name[$map[$i]], '<br/><br/>';
}
```